# Using a method from one class into a set

Tags: java, methods, types, set, hashset

I'm having problems getting a method from one class to work if I put the objects into a set.

So I have

```
public class Employee {
    /* instance variables */
    private String firstName;
    private String employeeNumber;


    public Employee(String employNum) {
        super();
        this.employeeNumber = employNum;             
    }
```

...

```
public String getFirstName() {
   return this.firstName;
}
```

There is lots of other code which I can post if needed but I'm not allowed to change the `Employee` class.

So for my code I have to create a class for a `Set` of `Employee`s which I've done with

```
public class Records {
    public Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<Employee>();

    public Records() {
    }
}
```

Now I need a method that will print the details of all employees in the set. Here is my attempt so far

```
public void printEmployeeNames() {
    for (String employee : employeeSet) {
        System.out.println(this.employeeSet.getFirstName());
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that it won't compile as it says

> "incompatible types"

and highlights `employeeSet` in

```
for (String employee : employeeSet)
```

My other problem is that it can't access the method for `getFirstName()`. I've tried to isolate the method using

```
public void printEmployeeNames() {
    System.out.println(this.employeeSet.getFirstName());
}
```

This also won't compile as it states

> "cannot find symbol - method getFirstName()".

Edit.
Thanks for the help with this problem, I changed it to this and it worked.

```
public void printEmployees()
   {
     for (Employee employee: employeeSet)
     {
        System.out.println(employee.getFirstName());
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this here makes no sense:

```
for (String employee: employeeSet)
 {
    System.out.println(this.employeeSet.getFirstName());
 }
```

since the employeeSet is a Set and sets dont have a method called getFirstName

## you have to do:

```
for (Employee employee: employeeSet) //for every EMPLOYEE in the employeeSet
 {
    System.out.println(employee.getFirstName()); //from that employ get the name
 }
```

AND create in the Employee class the respective Setter and getters

in this case:

```
private String firstName;
    
    /**
     * @return the employeeNumber
     */
    public final String getEmployeeNumber() {
        return firstName;
    }
```

Comment: The getter and setter methods were already there, I just didn't include them for brevity. Thank you for the help though

Answer (score 1):

That should be

```
for (Employee employee: employeeSet)
 {
    System.out.println(employee.getFirstName());
 }
```

`Set` doesn't have a firstname method. Your `employee` object have have.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you heard of [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))? The declaration `public Set<Employee> employeeSet` is an example of a bad practice, and you should use a private field with some sort of getter. The reason your `for` loop is raising errors is that you made two mistakes:

1. `employeeSet` is a `List<Employee>`, whereas you are asking for a `String` when iterating over it. This is incorrect - change the type of `employee` to `Employee`.
2. You are trying to access `getFirstName()` from your field `employeeSet`. This won't work, as [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) has no such method. I believe you meant to call the method on `employee`.

Also, you may simplify your code to the following one-liner with [Java 8 streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
public void printEmployeeNames() {
    employeeSet.stream().map(Employee::getFirstName).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```